# Get values of dynamically named inputs in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In my fees-list.component.html template, I have something like the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let meta of fees">

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
      <th>Amount owing (AUD)</th>
      <th>Fee type</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Amount to pay (AUD)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let fee of meta.fee">
      <td>{{ fee.balance }}</td>
      <td>{{ fee.type.desc }}</td>
      <td>{{ fee.title }}</td>
      <td><input id="{{ fee.id }}" type="text" name="toPay" value="{{ fee.balance }}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Total to pay: </strong><input type="text" name="total" value="{{ meta.total_sum }}"> </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The requirement for my interface is twofold. If users change the value of an individual fee (fee.balance), the value in the total text input field should be updated.
Secondly, if the total input field is updated, I need to update the value(s) in the individual fees accordingly (reducing those by the appropriate amount from oldest fee to newest fee).

My question is, how do I do binding for these input fields which are dynamically generated, though they do have unique ids (id="{{ fee.id }})? I cannot work out how to target an individual fee field in my typescript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two way binding with ngModel

```
<input [name]="fee.id" type="text" [(ngModel)]="fee.balance">
```

Now when the user types in the textbox it will update the value in the array directly.

Also you should not be using {{}} binding on your attributes like that, use attribute binding with the [box] syntax.

```
<input type="text" name="total" [value]="total_sum">
```

You can calculate the total in your TypeScript like

```
get total_sum() {
    return meta.fees.reduce((total, fee) => total + fee.balance, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach ( preferred) is to create the controls dynamically.

your typescript file :

```
  constructor(){
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup();

     const controls = meta.fee.map((fee)=>{
         this.formGroup.addControl(fee.id, new FormControl(fee.balance))
     });

    // now you have a formGroup with all the controls and their value are initialized, you just need to use it in your template 
  }
```

your template :

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let fee of meta.fee">
      <td>{{ fee.balance }}</td>
      <td>{{ fee.type.desc }}</td>
      <td>{{ fee.title }}</td>
      <td><input id="{{ fee.id }}" [formControl]="formGroup.get(fee.id)" type="text" name="toPay"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

So obviously, after this, you have the full power to do anything, for example, if you want to update a specific one of them:

```
  updateValue(){
   this.formGroup.get('oneOfThoseFeeIds').setValue('new value')
  }
```

NOTE : 
I haven't done Angular for a while and don't remember the exact syntaxes, but I hope this gives you a path

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use a service for that? I guess this is a way to go here, since you should try keeping your components as small as possible and communicate them by services.

Please, have a look at this chapter in angular documentation: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: I have a fees service which uses a node API, but my question is not so much architectural but technical/syntax-related c.f. two-way binding ie. reacting to changes in individual fee values - how to update the total when the fee fields are dynamically created?